# Trackpad gesture that minimizes all windows?

Tags: dock, trackpad

This has been driving me nuts for close to a year. I hope someone can tell me what triggers it. I've searched many times over several months and have never found any mention of it.

I use an MBP running OS X 10.8.3 with external monitors, external keyboard and external trackpad. Occasionally while I am manipulating windows with the trackpad (usually moving them by dragging, I think) all of the open windows for all apps will begin minimizing to the dock, one at a time, using the genie effect. Depending on the number of windows I have open, this can take several seconds. I have no idea what, specifically, I'm doing that triggers this behavior.

It is NOT "show desktop" -- the windows definitely fly down to the dock and are minimized, they do not slide to the edges of the screen. The windows are not hidden -- they don't come back with cmd-tab, for example, and they don't disappear instantly -- they "genie" down to the dock. The closest I've found is option-cmd-M, except that it only minimizes windows for the current app -- the behavior I'm asking about minimizes ALL windows from ALL apps.

Help? Please? Thanks!

Comment: Check your Dock settings under Apple.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I'm not trying to enable the behavior -- it already works. I'm trying to figure out what triggers it.

Comment: @user49032 I am sorry about my misunderstanding. Try Activity Monitor to see if any new process launches itself when all those windows start minimizing. Also check the logs and maybe something will be logged if lucky.
Another thing to do is creating a new account to see if the problem is account-specific.

Comment: @Buscar웃 My dock preferences have three settings that affect minimization (genie effect: enabled, double click title bar to minimize: disabled, and minimize into app icon: disabled). None seem to have anything to do with what I'm seeing. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ShaneHsu I'll check the logs, which I hadn't thought of. Catching it with activity monitor will be tough, since I trigger it by accident once every few weeks and so can't reproduce it at will.

Comment: The Dock setting do have a double click option for the title bar to minimise. But you would need to be holding the alt key down for all of an apps windows to slide down to the dock. And they would all go at once. But worth checking your settings

Comment: On my Mac I used to have the settings when I drag 4 fingers down the trackpad it will minimize all the windows on screen.

Comment: Maybe this is too late, but my best guess is that you have a 3rd party app installed, which interprets your gestures. Check your `/Applications` folder, see anything related to Trackpad gestures.

Answer (score 2):

I've found no default bindings that would make this occur, but I have found an application that possibly could be triggering what's occuring. There is a background application called MagicPrefs which allows for the addition of non-default bindings. MagicPrefs would also allow you to bind AppleScript to things like this as well.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. It looks like it could be pretty useful. Unfortunately, I don't have it installed, so it's not the cause of my problem :)

Comment: There's a keyboard shortcut to close all windows, Command-Option-W, but I can't imagine when you're dragging windows you're accidentally hitting that and I haven't found anything else under default.

Comment: And command-option-W closes windows for the current app. My thing minimizes, not closes, and it's all apps not just the current one.

Comment: Hm. Well, Cmd-Alt-(Click on Desktop) hides all windows. Cmd-Opt-M minimizes the window genie style. Cmd-Opt-H hides all but the top window. The behavior you're describing is how AppleScript would handle a command to "Minimize" all windows (It would genie minimize like Cmd-Opt-M, and do them one at a time). I'd assume you would know if you had an AppleScript that was doing this with some sort of link. Is there any more info?

Comment: So I think I understand that Cmd-Opt-M minimizes all windows for the current app. I just tried it and that's what it did. For the behavior in question, I'm seeing all windows for all apps minimized genie style. I assume what you're saying is that AppleScript could minimize all windows for all apps, not that Cmd-Opt-M does that by itself. Regardless, I don't have any reason to think that I installed a script on my system to do this, and I got the computer new from Apple.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. Basically I'm not finding any information about a default way to do this, to the point where I'm finding significant information regarding applescript methods to perform the function you're requesting. That's why I'm confused and thinking there is a missing link here that's the crucial gateway to understanding.

Comment: Did you *ever* install MagicPrefs or anything like it? Have you looked through Launch Agents and Launch Demons in both Libraries? Login Items?

Comment: @Zo219 I have never installed MagicPrefs or anything similar. Looking at Launch Agents and Launch Demons in both libraries doesn't show anything unexpected and I think I can rule out everything there, unless something is behaving completely out of character (like logmein or my VPN client being responsible -- those are the sorts of things that are there).I appreciate your help, but it looks like this will remain a mystery until I figure out what sequence of movements is triggering it, and maybe that will be a clue.

Comment: Sandboxing, I think, is storing whole copies of apps at system level, and this damn container thing. Sometimes even App Support. I use EasyFind so as not to go mad ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is triggered when you have the cursor over the dock...
three fingers down over a window shows all the similar windows open..
three fingers down when the cursor is over the dock hides everything including anything on the deskop.

Answer (score -2):

BetterTouchTool, from http://blog.boastr.net, offers many window-related functions, such as minimize/maximize/resize and many more. Each action can be assigned to a different trackpad gesture (which you can choose!).

Just as an example: I set up my computer to maximize windows using three finger taps on the top of the window, four finger taps to drag windows, tiptaps to close windows any many more. Check it out!

Answer (score -3):

three fingers swipe up will do what you are telling about, I think.  it works on my Dell